# Translating a line from Matlab (bsxfun with plus) to Python

Tags: python, matlab, distance

I am trying to compute Hamming Distance in python in most optimal way and i found one interesting implementation in Matlab

```
Dist = sqrt(bsxfun(@plus,sum(A.^2,2),sum(B.^2,2)') - 2*(A*B') );
```

How can I translate it to Python? I don't uderstand what bsxfun is doing here.

Answer (score 2):

That's *Euclidean* distance, not Hamming distance. Also, you have a *complex conjugate* transpose in `A*B'`, but you are not conjugating the matrices in `A.^2`, `B.^2`, so I assume your matrices are real.

The Matlab code in your question uses [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which is Matlab's higher-level function for singleton expansion (broadcasting). The equivalent code in Python using [Numpy's broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array(A)
B = np.array(B)
Dist = np.sqrt((A**2).sum(1, keepdims=True) + (B**2).sum(1, keepdims=True).T - 2*np.dot(A, B.T))
```

In Matlab, it could also be done more compactly (with the Statistics Toolbox) as

```matlab
Dist = pdist2(A, B);
```

The equivalent version in Python (with Scipy) is

```py
import scipy.spatial
Dist = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(A, B, 'euclidean')
```

Comment: I think it is clearer and more compact to do `(A**2).sum(1, keepdims=True) + (B**2).sum(1, keepdims=True).T`. And on modern versions of python and numpy you can replace the last part with `2*(A@B.T)`

Comment: You're using NumPy.  I'm shedding a tear.

Comment: @rayryeng Don't tell Matlab I've been with another language

Comment: @TheBlackCat Thanks. Python / Numpy noob here

Comment: @LuisMendo The nice thing about NumPy is that when you perform calculations on NumPy arrays, what is returned are also NumPy arrays and the array has built-in methods, such as sum, mean, etc.... so doing `(A**2).sum()` will actually return an array of elements that are squared individually, and you invoke its `sum` method.  I love NumPy because of its eloquent use of temporary variables.

Answer (score -1):

You know MATLAB is very rich in documentation. The time you spent in stack to ask a question will fetch more information by reading documentation.

Well *bsxfun* applies element-wise operation to two arrays with implicit expansion enabled. Say, you want to apply any function (+,-,mean,xor,min,max...etc) between a matrix and corresponding rows or columns, we use *bsxfun* insteading of using repeating/ extending the rows/cols of second data to the matrix size. Say, I want to add eaxh row of 3x3 matrix with 1x3 row, I have to repeat the array 1x3 three times, to make it to 3x3 and then add. This can be done directly using *bsxfun*

Example:

```
A = rand(3) ;
B = rand(1,3) ;
C = bsxfun(@plus, A, B);
% is same as
C1 = repmat(B,3,1) ;
```

There are certain functions you can use with *bsxfun* which you can get from documentation.
https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html

Comment: While this is a good explanation, it does not answer the simple question of what is the python parallel.